# Create an Image with ProPhtoto RGB as the colour space

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Ubuntu as my Operating System, and I want to create an image for my android wallpaper, how can I create an Image with `PIL` (pillow) with the `ProPhoto RGB` colour space ?

```
from PIL import Image

# colour space, size, RGB
im = Image.new('ProPhotoRGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))
>>> Unrecognized image mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible, for several reasons:

- ProPhoto is not one of PIL's [supported modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes),
- you would almost certainly want 16 bits/channel for that, and PIL doesn't support 16-bit/channel RGB (see link above)
- ProPhoto would actually require the RGB ROMM ICC profile, and I don't believe PIL can include ICC profiles in TIFF files.

I may be mistaken, I have been before, so if anyone knows better, please ping me.